# hierarchy relationship power pivot

Tags: powerpivot

I m trying to show a table where sales are broken down by each sales person with their respective target 
I would like to do it in the most efficient way as possible which I think mean fewer table as possible,

District are unique in Geographic split table,

I would like to show for each sales person their sales and target as  in results table ..I think I ll have to go through hierarchy but I m not sure how to go about it

I have tried create a table for district and table for sales force with unique columns...but I can get them to show in one table without creating table for each type of sales force.

Thanks for any advice

[image]

Comment: How is the `Target` table related to the `Geograpic Split` table? For `Geograpic Split` I see we have `District` a connection to `Sales`... but can't understand how Target should relate to `Geograpic Split`

Comment: @Wizhi  the sales force column on Target Table are the same Reps, Managers, Director on Geographic table

Comment: Then I think what you want to achieve is not possible :(. Usually when you build a database you need something that is common across the tables.. You need something that has a explicit relationship... otherwise powerpivot doesn't know how to link the tables to each other. 
[table relationships in databases](https://howto.caspio.com/tables-and-views/relationships/). One way could be to assign each person a unique person ID that could be linked in both the geographical and target table..